# xamarin.forms skiasharp app size is larger than the given demos?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

First of all `skiasharp` is a wonderful library for 2D drawings on cross-platform.
I have tried its demo and its very interesting.
So I decided to make application using `skiasharp`. But its going to be little big if every thing goes smooth. :)

So, the issue I found in my app that is app size. I made app with 3-4 pages. And in one of them I've implemented 2D drawing.

So only with these app size goes upto 41 MB-Using linking option `SDK Assemblies only`. If I change my linking option to `SDK And User Assemblies` It shrinks to 27MB.

I tried this linking options on the given [demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/SkiaSharpForms/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/). Its size with 1st linking option is 35 MB. and it contains lots of pages and classes. And when I changed to 2nd linking option, demo app crashes.

I want to know the reason why my app size is much larger that the demo even if I have few pages. and why demo app not running for the linking option `SDK and User Assembly`

Please help! Thanks! :)